# Is there a way to hide axes for all subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to plot two images side by side without any junk like grid lines and axes. I found that you can turn off ALL grid lines with `plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False`, but can't figure out if there's a similar option for axes. I know you can use `plt.axis('off')` but then you'd have to specify it for each subplot individually.

```
plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(img1)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(img2)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

The different components of the axes all have their individual rc parameter. So to turn "everything off", you would need to set them all to  `False`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rc = {"axes.spines.left" : False,
      "axes.spines.right" : False,
      "axes.spines.bottom" : False,
      "axes.spines.top" : False,
      "xtick.bottom" : False,
      "xtick.labelbottom" : False,
      "ytick.labelleft" : False,
      "ytick.left" : False}
plt.rcParams.update(rc)

img = np.random.randn(100).reshape(10,10)

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax.imshow(img)
ax2.imshow(img)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One option is to loop through the axes on the figure and turn them off. You need to create the figure object and then use [`fig.axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.axes) which returns a list of subplots :

```
img = np.random.randn(100).reshape(10,10)

fig = plt.figure()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(img)

for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.axis("off")
```

[image]

You could also go through the rcParams and set all the spines, ticks, and tick labels to False.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
plt.axis('off')
```

And:

```
plt.grid(False)
```

Instead, whole code would be:

```
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(img1)
plt.axis('off')
plt.grid(False)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(img2)
plt.axis('off')
plt.grid(False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: That doesn't work. `plt.axis('off')` has to go after the line where subplot is created, and it only applies to that subplot