# matplotlib: why does setting grid with pyplot.setp() causes error?

Tags: python, matplotlib

this question is different from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53716165/10253483), which is discussing other ways to set grid rather than using pyplot.setp().

matplotlib.pyplot.setp() could be used to set some properties for all subplots.

this piece of code

```
xlim = (-2,2)
ylim = (-2,2)
f, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
a = plt.setp(axs, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
plt.show()
```

sets limits as (-2,2) for all subplots.

AxesSubplot.grid could be used to set grid lines

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axs[0,0].grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to set grid lines by using pyplot.setp().

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.setp(axs, grid=True)
plt.show()
```

get this error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5014b2a61ed3> in <module>()
      1 f, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
----> 2 plt.setp(axs, grid=True)
      3 plt.show()

~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in setp(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    340 @docstring.copy(_setp)
    341 def setp(obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 342     return _setp(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    343 
    344 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in setp(obj, *args, **kwargs)
   1505     # put args into ordereddict to maintain order
   1506     funcvals = OrderedDict((k, v) for k, v in zip(args[::2], args[1::2]))
-> 1507     ret = [o.update(funcvals) for o in objs] + [o.set(**kwargs) for o in objs]
   1508     return list(cbook.flatten(ret))
   1509 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1505     # put args into ordereddict to maintain order
   1506     funcvals = OrderedDict((k, v) for k, v in zip(args[::2], args[1::2]))
-> 1507     ret = [o.update(funcvals) for o in objs] + [o.set(**kwargs) for o in objs]
   1508     return list(cbook.flatten(ret))
   1509 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in set(self, **kwargs)
   1013                    key=lambda x: (self._prop_order.get(x[0], 0), x[0])))
   1014 
-> 1015         return self.update(props)
   1016 
   1017     def findobj(self, match=None, include_self=True):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in update(self, props)
    914 
    915         with cbook._setattr_cm(self, eventson=False):
--> 916             ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
    917 
    918         if len(ret):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    914 
    915         with cbook._setattr_cm(self, eventson=False):
--> 916             ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
    917 
    918         if len(ret):

~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in _update_property(self, k, v)
    910                 func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
    911                 if not callable(func):
--> 912                     raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
    913                 return func(v)
    914 

AttributeError: Unknown property grid
```

I am asking for an explanation why this code causes error rather than a solution to set grid for all subplots.

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation why your code causes error or a solution to set grid for all subplots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use `plt.setp` to turn the grid on.

The reason is that the axes does not have an attribute `grid` and no `set_grid` method, but only a method `.grid(..)`.

You would need to call that method,

```
for ax in axs.flat:
    ax.grid(True)
```

Other options to turn the grid on are shown in [How do I draw a grid onto a plot in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209568/how-do-i-draw-a-grid-onto-a-plot-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `rcParams`. You can use the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rc = {"axes.grid" : True}
plt.rcParams.update(rc)

xlim = (-2,2)
ylim = (-2,2)
f, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
a = plt.setp(axs, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
plt.show()
```

[image]