# Apply method to every object of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `np.array` of objects and I want to apply the same method to each object in this array. For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2,)
```

now I want gridlines in every axes object. I know I can do this by iterating over the `ax` array with an for-loop.

```py
for i in ax:
    i.grid()
```

Is there a more elegant method? Like `np.somefunction(array, method)`.

Comment: This helps a lot in this special case, but in a general case where you have an array of objects you cannot do that. But thanks for your help

Comment: I suppose it really depends on what type of objects you are dealing with.

Comment: An object dtype array is more like a list of objects than a numeric array.  So iteration or list comprehension is usually just as good.  There is a `np.frompyfunc` function that can make such a call 'prettier', but doesn't change the speed much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using matplotlib, [`plt.setp`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.setp.html) would normally be an option to set properties on multiple axes at the same time. Setting the grid is one thing you can't do with `setp` unfortunately (e.g., [matplotlib: why does setting grid with pyplot.setp() causes error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56894740/2988730)). Instead, you can modify [`mpl.rcParams`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rcParams). You can do this temporarily for your figure using [`mpl.rc_context`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc_context):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, rc_context

with rc_context(rc={"axes.grid": True}:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

The figures in the context manager looks like this:

[image]

The other, like this:

[image]

If you are looking for a general purpose method for applying a function to your array, well, there isn't really one: [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35215161/2988730).